# Phonegap: Fast way of testing Camera-Functions, without building app

Tags: android, html, testing, cordova, cordova-3

I've decided to take a closer look at Phonegap, which means currently I'm not developing anything, but trying different things, e.g. the camera. Apparently this can't be tested with Ripple for Chrome - as far as I know it needs to be tested either in the emulator or on the device itself. My computer isn't slow, but building an app and installing it either on the emulator or the device still takes "a lot" of time (if you're just playing around).

So my question now: Is there any way of speeding up the process of testing applications e.g. in the computer's browser even if you are using things like camera?

Here are the things I've tried so far:

- Using my Sony Xperia Mini Pro
- Using Intel-Android-Image
- Booting emulator from snapshot
- Ripple (which can emulate a lot, but not the camera)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up building the app each time, it's kind of fast if you use build scripts.

But you can also try cordova browser https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eas.cordova.browser

or Cordova Fast https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.Bellinux.CordovaFast

I haven't tried the latter myself though.
cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thing I'm going to stick to my Ubuntu-Aliases. At least they make the typing fast ;) To bad, that Ripple can't emulate the Cam. I guess one answer in five hours is a hint, that there really aren't better solutions yet.